# How can I get all info about what file extensions each of my installed extensions' provided language(s) associates with?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to find reference connection between VS Code Language ID and its file extensions? For example, `javascript` is `.js`, `.mjs`, `.cjs` .etc, whereas `javascriptreact` is only `.jsx`. I know that we can get this information from the package.json of each extension in [`microsoft/vcsode`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a9c43b529208adb3d819800c9cfc1178033265d2/extensions/javascript/package.json#L17) but is there a page that shows all the mapping?

[image]

There is this page (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) but it doesn't show what extensions the id corresponding to.

Answer (score 0):

Given a package.json file, you can query for the fields of interest using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) with `jq ".contributes|.languages|.[]|({id:.id,extensions:.extensions})"`.

VS Code's builtin extensions  are stored in

- `.../usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/` on Linux
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\` on Windows
- <I don't know but something similar> on macOS (I don't have my mac on me right now)

User-installed extension are stored in `~/.vscode/extensions/`.

So you could get a list of extension package.json files with [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

`rg -l '"languages"' --glob="package.json" -- .../resources/app/extensions/ $HOME/.vscode/extensions/`

So for example, on my Ubuntu machine (where I have VS Code installed as a Snap), I do `jq ".contributes|.languages|.[]|({id:.id,extensions:.extensions})" $(rg -l '"languages"' --glob="package.json" -- /snap/code/current/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/ $HOME/.vscode/extensions/)`.